# The best way to parse the following object

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I need to parse the following object.

The code I implemented (2) works partially.
Please, see the comment in (1) and if you can give me some hints how to fix the code (2) I will appreciate.

My goal is to  call the parser_2 just when I have the errors key in the root object.
I am using jquery and underscore.

---

(1)

```
parser({
    "errors": ["errro1"], // it should be passed to parser_2
                          // with the code I implemented it works
    "children": {
        "points": {
            "errors": ["This value should not be blank.", "error2"]
        },
        "message": [], // it should be passed to parser
                       // with the code I implemented it does not work
                       // because it calls parser_2 instead of parser or nothing!
        "recipient_id": {
            "errors": ["This value should not be blank."]
        }
    }
});
```

---

(2)

```
parser = function (object) {
    _.each(object, function (object, name) {
        if (object.errors) {
            var inputElement = element.find('[name="' + name + '"]');
            //other code
        } else if ($.isArray(object)) {
            parser_2(object);
        } else if ($.isPlainObject(object)) {
            parser(object);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: What should it do instead? You're calling `parser_2` in case of an array, which your code clearly shows.

Comment: Yes, I should call the parser_2 just when I have the errors key at the first level. this is my goal.

Comment: Please edit (or add details to) your question [How should I deal with an object who looks like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175050/how-should-i-deal-with-an-object-who-looks-like-this) instead of asking a new one

Comment: It seems like you actually want to loop over object.children, not the object itself. What makes the "root object" special? Why should the empty array be passed into `parser`?

Answer (score 0):

You can distinguish the root object with nested objects by checking whether the current call is the first call or a recursive call:

```
parser = function (object, firstCall) {
    _.each(object, function (object, name) {
        if (firstCall && $.isArray(object)) {
            parser_2(object);
        } else if (object.errors) {
            var inputElement = element.find('[name="' + name + '"]');
            //other code
        } else if ($.isPlainObject(object)) {
            parser(object);  // don't pass `true` here
        }
    });
};
```

Then you call it with `parser(..., true)`.

By the way, naming both the input object and nested objects `object` is confusing.

Comment: +1 Thanks, and which name do you suggest to distinguish  input object from nested object?

Comment: @Lorraine Bernard: That depends on what the objects represent. `object` isn't really meaningful to me; I think you're the one knowing best what the objects represent :)